# problem installing setup files for windows

Tags: windows

I have downloaded and used wine for installing the Windows setup file. Are there any other ways to run setup files of windows.

Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Do you just mean installing Windows applications or are you thinking of another use?

Answer (score 0):

as the best alternative to wine I can suggest you playonlinux , which is also have ability to run windows applications in Ubuntu.

to install it open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

That will install playonlinux in your Ubuntu.

More information you can find here : [playonlinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/documentation.html)